# How to prove $1-L_{\infty} ~ Norm$ is non-convex (concave) function?

Tags: real-analysis, optimization, convex-analysis

I know that $L_\infty$ norm is convex and the 1-convex function will lead to a concave function.

My attempt to shows this as: 
\begin{align}
\|(1 - \lambda)x + \lambda y\|_\infty
  & \le (1 - \lambda)\|x\|_\infty + \lambda\|y\|_\infty & &
\text{Condition of convexity}\\
-\|(1 - \lambda)x + \lambda y\|_\infty
  & \geq -(1 - \lambda)\|x\|_\infty -\lambda\|y\|_\infty\\
1-\|(1 - \lambda)x + \lambda y\|_\infty
  & \geq 1-(1 - \lambda)\|x\|_\infty -\lambda\|y\|_\infty & & \text{Condition of convcavity}
\end{align}

Now, if this is correct, what is the convex overestimation of $1-\|x\|_\infty$?

Comment: Hint: write the $1$ on the right hand side as $(1 - \lambda) + \lambda$.

Comment: @user754697 can you please elaborate?

Comment: Every function $f(x) = 1-g(x)$ with functional $g$ satisfying $\|g\|\le1$ will be a convex overestimator.

Comment: @daw Do you mean that with condition $\|x\|_\infty \leq 1$ the above function is convex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To complete the argument, note that
\begin{align*}
1-(1 - \lambda)\|x\|_\infty -\lambda\|y\|_\infty &= (1 - \lambda) - (1 - \lambda)\|x\|_\infty + \lambda - \lambda\|y\|_\infty \\
&= (1 - \lambda)(1 - \|x\|_\infty) + \lambda(1 - \|y\|_\infty),
\end{align*}
finishing the proof of concavity.

Comment: What about the convex overestimator of the $1-\|x\|_\infty$?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but [daw](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/136544/daw) seems to.

Comment: I mean can I find a convex $g(x)$ such that $1-\|x\|_\infty \leq g(x)$.

Comment: Sure. The function $g(x) = 1$ is convex and majorises $1 - \|x\|_\infty$.

Comment: Yes but this is not a very good estimator. Error is equal to the $\|x\|_\infty$.

Comment: I didn't realise that this was a requirement. I doubt you're going to find a much better estimator (however you're measuring these things). If you tilt the hyperplane, you'll get better estimates in some directions but worse in others, and any convex majorising function will have a hyperplane sandwiched between it and the graph of $1 - \|x\|_\infty$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105152/discussion-between-parikshit-pareek-and-user754697).